# Python Pandas Groupby seems to be eliminating rows from my data

Tags: python, pandas

If I do

```
rr = pd.read_csv( 'refinedRatings.csv' ) 
lookrr = rr.loc[rr['user_id'] == 1]
lookrr.head(30)
```

My data looks something like this

```
Unnamed:0   user_id book_id rating
0                0              1   258    5
59           78         1    1796  5
148900  230483  1   4691    4
148901  230485  1   2063    4
148902  230489  1   11     5
148903  230490  1   1644    5
148904  230492  1   136    5
148905  230493  1   6665    4
148906  230495  1   35  5
148907  230496  1   33  4
148908  230500  1   10  4
148909  230502  1   4        5
148910  230505  1   1521    5
148911  230506  1   70  5
148912  230509  1   36  4
148913  230512  1   32  4
148914  230513  1   13  4
148915  230514  1   66  4
```

Since it's not really clear due to stackoverflow formatting, here's an image
https://snag.gy/FyanEs.jpg

But if I use group by like this

```
rr = pd.read_csv( 'refinedRatings.csv' ) 
rrgb= rr.groupby('user_id')
rrgb.head(200)
```

Then the data looks like this

```
Unnamed: 0  user_id book_id rating
0   0   1   258 5
1   1   2   4081    4
2   2   2   260 5
3   3   2   9296    5
4   5   2   26  4
5   7   2   33  4
6   8   2   301 5
7   9   2   2686    5
8   10  2   3753    5
9   11  2   8519    5
10  12  4   70  4
11  14  4   388 4
12  15  4   18  5
13  16  4   27  5
14  17  4   21  5
15  18  4   2   5
16  19  4   23  5
17  20  4   24  5
```

again, image 
https://snag.gy/JugXGe.jpg

So it seems that the group by operation is eliminating several rows where the 'user_id' is equal to 1.

Is there any explanation to this?

Here's a direct link to the data

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v7Mm6S8BVtou1iIfobY43LRF8MgGdjfU

Also for the original source of the data

https://github.com/zygmuntz/goodbooks-10k

Edit:

I also set the index to `user_id` and the result is the same as when I used `groupby`

code

```
rrfinal = pd.read_csv( 'refinedRatings.csv' ).set_index('user_id')
rrfinal.head(50)
```

results

```
Unnamed: 0  book_id rating
user_id         
1   0   258 5
2   1   4081    4
2   2   260 5
2   3   9296    5
2   5   26  4
2   7   33  4
2   8   301 5
2   9   2686    5
2   10  3753    5
2   11  8519    5
4   12  70  4
4   14  388 4
4   15  18  5
4   16  27  5
4   17  21  5
4   18  2   5
4   19  23  5
4   20  24  5
```

Again, picture of the results
https://snag.gy/RJTPvt.jpg

Edit:

As a precaution, I converted all the entries into str, then back into int.

```
rr = rr.applymap(str)
rr = rr.applymap(int)
```

This made no different. All the results from the code above are the same. However, what is interesting, after applying the datatype change, if I look for all entries with string, it gives me the exact same data as if I did 'groupby' like from before

```
rr[rr['user_id'].apply(lambda x: type(x)==str)]
rr.head(200)
```

Result

```
    Unnamed: 0  user_id book_id rating
0   0   1   258 5
1   1   2   4081    4
2   2   2   260 5
3   3   2   9296    5
4   5   2   26  4
5   7   2   33  4
6   8   2   301 5
7   9   2   2686    5
8   10  2   3753    5
9   11  2   8519    5
```

And again, picture of result https://snag.gy/QarSCN.jpg

Comment: Is that Chocolat text editor or do you just like Comic Sans? :P But for real, are you *sure* the values in each column are all the same DataType? That's a common culprit for this, some strings mixed in with numbers.

Comment: lol the font is lexie readable with alterations. But actually I don't know. I got it off a github data set, will investigate. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: okay I just used df.dtypes and it said all the columns are int64 . Anyone know if there's a possibility that it would ignore a 2nd data type? df.info() gave same info

Comment: seems that’s not the problem. If the data are on GitHub, consider linking to it (if public) as it will make it easier to assist.

Comment: Updated the opening post with the original data, here https://github.com/zygmuntz/goodbooks-10k and the refined data I'm using with a direct link to my gdrive file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SantoshGupta7: I assure you that your data are not being eliminated. It appears that way because the [DataFrameGroupBy.head](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) function preserves the original order of the dataframe. If you call .count() or any other aggregation function on your groupby object, you will see all of your data are still there.

To approximate the .head() behavior you're expecting, you can do the following:

```
rr = pd.read_csv('refinedRatings.csv') 
rrgb = rr.groupby('user_id')

print(rrgb.apply(lambda x: x.head(200)))

                 Unnamed: 0  user_id  book_id  rating
user_id                                              
1       0                 0        1      258       5
        59               78        1     1796       5
        148900       230483        1     4691       4
        148901       230485        1     2063       4
        148902       230489        1       11       5
        148903       230490        1     1644       5
        148904       230492        1      136       5
        148905       230493        1     6665       4
        148906       230495        1       35       5
        148907       230496        1       33       4
        148908       230500        1       10       4
        148909       230502        1        4       5
        148910       230505        1     1521       5
        148911       230506        1       70       5
        148912       230509        1       36       4
        148913       230512        1       32       4
```

You'll notice that the "user_id" column is still present. That's down to the particular nature of the groupby.head function and/or the fact that you haven't yet performed any aggregation on the data.

Please see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17775 for a discussion of the "head" issue.